# Modify joomla! website

Tags: joomla, filezilla

i've for mission to modify ( in my hard disk) a joomla! website that his owner didn't give me any informations for security reasons.

my question is how to get this website on my hard disk, is there a way ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Joomla! extension Akeeba Backup to back-up the website.  Then download that back-up to your PC and use Akeeba's tool Kickstart to install the site on your local PC.  You will of course also need to run a web server, PHP, and MySQL on your machine such as the package that comes in XAMPP.

Comment: I think you did not undrestand well the question, because it's not a save/back up question. there is a website i would like to put it on my pc  without having his administrator Id and pass, is it doable ?

Comment: Yes it is. You will have to manually download the entire site via FTP and also download a dump of the database.  Once you have done that you will need to run a web server, PHP, and MySQL on you local machine.  You will have to then put the downloaded site in the proper root directory and rebuild the database locally.  Once you have the database rebuilt you can change the admin user and pass via phpmyadmin.  You will also need to understand how Joomla! works and adjust the necessary config settings in Joomla!'s config file.

Comment: all my question is how to download this website, i don't have any Id or pass, i tried on filezilla, but i doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: If you can't do it via FTP, via the hosting account, or via logging into Joomla! admin then you can not do it at all.