# Save a joomla website on my pc without Id & pass

Tags: web, joomla

A client is asking to improve his website but can't give me the admin id & pass (for security reasons).

Is there a way to put his joomla website in my hard disk in order to work on it ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify joomla! website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210152/modify-joomla-website)

Comment: right, i explained again, because it was misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be for the client to set up a new super administrator account, then make a backup copy of the website using Akeeba Backup. You can then install that copy on your PC or server to do the necessary work. When you are done, simply make a new backup and have them restore from your backup to update the live site.

When they update they can remove the additional super admin account they set up for you.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606